# Set URL query parameters without state change using Angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, url, angular-ui-router, query-string

How should I update the address bar URL with a changing query parameter using AngularJS' ui-router to maintain state when refreshing the page?

Currently, I am using `$state.transitionTo('search', {q: 'updated search term'})` whenever input changes, but the problem is that this reloads the controller, redraws the window and loses any text input focus.

Is there a way to update stateParams and sync it to the window URL?

Comment: I've noticed $state.go() does not reload the controller if you direct it to the same state that you're in with just the parameters changing. Does this help you?

Comment: go will reload the controller : 
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go

Answer (score 80):

I was having trouble with .transitionTo until I updated to [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) 0.2.14.  0.2.14 properly changes the location bar (without reloading the controller) using a call like this:

```
$state.transitionTo('search', {q: 'updated search term'}, { notify: false });
```

Comment: best answer, least hackish

Comment: Finally something that works! Thanks @pmont
I was using dynamic: true in the params but not only was it not working consistently it is not even necessary if I follow your approach.

Comment: That's what I was looking for sweet n short.

Comment: **`notify`** *Boolean (default true)*, If `true` will broadcast `$stateChangeStart` and `$stateChangeSuccess` events.

Comment: `$state.go` calls `$state.transitionTo` internally but automatically sets options to `{ location: true, inherit: true, relative: $state.$current, notify: true }`. This allows you to easily use an absolute or relative to path and specify only the parameters you'd like to update (while letting unspecified parameters inherit from the current state.

Comment: But when I use this solution, it seems it will reload the components. I am using the latest Angular UI router 1.0.0.beta3

Comment: As per a ui-router maintainer: "using notify: false is almost never a good idea, and is now deprecated. Use reloadOnSearch if you must."

Comment: Thanks Alejandro for the update.  Notice that the version of ui-router at the time of my answer was 0.2.14, and notify was the only workable solution.  Much has changed since then.  What's unsettling to me is that 3.5 years later, 1.0.0 final release still hasn't been published.

Comment: @pmont not sure what you mean, the latest stable version is 1.0.20 and version 1.0.0 final was released on Jun 10, 2017. `reloadOnSearch` was introduced on version 0.2.5 (released before your answer as far as I know).

Comment: reloadOnSearch did not do what I (and many others) needed at the time.  Maybe it was buggy back then, but the point is that a lot has changed since 3.5 years ago.

Answer (score 28):

edit: Played around with this some more today, and realized that angular ui-router has a similar option as the native routerProvider: "reloadOnSearch".

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#options-1

It's set to `true` by default, but if you set it to `false` on your state, then the state change won't happen when the query parameters are changed.  You can then call `$location.search(params);` or `$location.search('param', value);` and the URL will change, but ui-router won't re-build the entire controller/view.  You'll probably also need to listen for the `$locationChangeStart` event on the root scope to handle back and forward history actions within your app, as these also won't cause state changes.

I'm also listening for the `$stateChangeSuccess` event on my controller's scope to capture the initial load of the page/route.

There is some discussion on github for using this feature with path changes (not just URL changes): https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/125 but I haven't tested that at all since my use case was specific to query string parameters.

The previous version of my answer mentioned this github issue:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/562

But that's a slightly separate issue, specifically showing a modal of one state over another state without the non-modal state changing.  I tried the patch in that issue, but it's clear that it isn't meant for preventing the entire state from reloading on URL change.

Comment: How do you get hold of the new search params after you do $location.search? After doing $location.search it seems $stateParams doesn't get updated and $routeParams doesn't have the new value.

Comment: @DownChapel I'd very much like to know myself

Comment: @DownChapel you will have to listen on $locationChangeStart in your controller and there you can use $location.search() to get the current query parameters

Answer (score 28):

**Update May 19, 2015**

As of ui-router 0.2.15, the issue of reloading the state on query parameter changes has been resolved. However, the new update broke the history API back and forward capabilities with query parameters. I have not been able to find a workaround for that.

**Original**

Jay's answer didn't work for me, and neither did a ton of other answers. Trying to listen to `$locationChangeStart` caused problems when trying to go back and forth in the browser history as it would cause me to run code twice: once when the new state changed and another because `$loationChangeStart` fired.

I tried using `reloadOnSearch=false`, but that [prevented state changes](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1079) even when the url path changed. So I finally got it to work by doing the following:

When you change `$location.search()` to update the query parameters, use a ["hack"](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1079#issuecomment-75068262) to temporarily disable reloading on search, set query parameters, then re-enable reloading.

```
$state.current.reloadOnSearch = false;

$location.search('query', [1,2]);

$timeout(function () {
  $state.current.reloadOnSearch = undefined;
});
```

This will ensure that query parameter changes do not reload the state and that url path changes will reload the state properly.

However, this didn't get the browsers history to change the state (needed for knowing when a query parameter changes to re-read the URL) when a query parameter was part of the url. So I also had to add each query parameter's name to the `url` property of the [state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters).

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/?param1&param2&param3',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl as home',
  });
```

Any parameter names on the url are optional when listed this way, but any changes to those parameter names will reload the state when hitting the back and forward buttons on the browser.

Hopefully others find this useful and it doesn't take them multiple days to figure out how to do it (like I did).

Comment: I am so pissed i did not find this sooner. I have an entire app designed around dealing with this bug and the hacks involved. I just implemented your reloadOnSearch hack into a nice method and it worked perfectly. Nice job.

Comment: This is THE correct answer without any side-effects. Great work! Easy and simple.

Comment: I did something similar to this, but ran into issues with values of $stateParams being injected into a resolve. At least with 0.2.15, params that have been changed in the URL, will revert back to their previous values, when transitioning from a child state back to the parent (at least, when provided into a resolve via $stateParams).

Comment: That does not work for me. anyone tested it recently on angular 1.6?

Comment: Its a hack but works for me in angular 1.8.0 + ui-router 1.0.27 including the history.
```if ($state.$current.navigable.params.hasOwnProperty('tab')) {
 $state.$current.navigable.params['tab'].dynamic = true;
}

$location.search(locationSearch);

$timeout(function () {
 currentState.reloadOnSearch = reloadOnSearchBefore;
 if ($state.$current.navigable.params.hasOwnProperty('tab')) {
  $state.$current.navigable.params['tab'].dynamic = false;
 }
});```