# Angular ui router and implementing overlay with back button

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having issues with an overlay panel.

The first page loads, you click a link... It pops up an overlay, the router fires a state and controller, and it populates the contents of the overlay.

There is a back button on the overlay, I trigger the overlay to close, call window.history.back() which sends the router off to load the new url (previous url) and it runs it through the router again but obviously refreshes the backing page in doing so.

So the end result is when you press a link, the overlay slides out beautifully, you then press back, the overlay slides back in, it then refreshes the page. You'd think then, why not just say in the controller, if there was an overlay and now there isn't do not change the view content... I can't, as the template stuff gets placed into the ui-view which is remove all my content.

So I need a way of changing the url without running through all of the controller stuff again so to avoid the template being inserted.

Any ideas on how to do this? Or examples of it working somewhere else.

Comment: The hack in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29262392/174184) answer helped me. Check if it solves your problem.

Comment: I'll add some code at a later date, see if that helps recognise the issue. The above link seems to delay the url changing, but inevitably it changes