# Change $stateParams with {notify:false} and no {resolve}

Tags: angular-ui-router

This relates to this question:
[Set URL query parameters without state change using Angular ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884551/set-url-query-parameters-without-state-change-using-angular-ui-router)
(I dont have enough points for a comment)

I'm using $state.go('state.name', {params}, {notify:false}) to update my url params and it works well.
The problem is I have defined 'resolve' services for this route and they are being called, and I don't really want that to happen, as it is unnecessary calls to the server.
I would expect {notify:false} to skip that too, Is there a way to skip the resolving?
Or even better - another elegant way to update state params with ease? (instead of $state.go()) ?

Comment: Solution is outlined at the end of this github issue thread: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2146